# How to calculate intrinsic, extrinsic and mean curvatures of a large sphere in $\mathbb{S}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Use the mobile referential method to calculate how curvatures (intrinsic, mean and extrinsic)
of a great sphere in $\mathbb{S}^3$ (with canonical metric).

My teacher explained that a great sphere in $\mathbb{S}^3$ is analogous to a great circle in $\mathbb{S}^2$. You can take a definition of a vector subspace of dimension 3 within $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$ within $\mathbb{R}^4$.

For example, if you use Cartesian coordinates $ x, y, z, w $ for $\mathbb{R}^4$ the equation of $\mathbb{S}^3$, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1$, if you intersect $\mathbb{S}^3$ with the hyperplane defined by equation $w = 0$ you will get the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with coordinates $(x, y, z, 0)$.

I am not very well aware of the geometry involved and how to put these ideas on paper.

Comment: Do you see geometrically how to handle circles in the sphere? (It's not clear to me whether your last sentence refers to the full $S^{3}$, or to $S^{2}$ as well.) Once you understand that picture, construct a moving frame and verify the conclusions. Then extend to $S^{3}$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think it refers to the $\mathbb{S}^3$. I don't remember working with circles in the sphere.  It's different for me, this discipline started with understandable ideas (differential forms, Poincare's Lemma, etc.) and took a course that I can't follow

Comment: I believe that you're talking about *great* (rather than large) circles and spheres. These are the intersections with hyperplanes through the origin. Here's a hint to get you going: You want an adapted orthonormal frame $e_0;e_1,e_2;e_3$ with $e_0=x$ the position vector (which is also the unit normal to $S^3\subset\Bbb R^4$) and $e_1,e_2$ tangent to your surface in $S^3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks, is great sphere.

Comment: My difficulty is precisely to start such problems, I will try with your suggestions. @TedShifrin and Andrew, thanks.